# Composite indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm having a table in database with column a,b,c,d,e. I created a composite index on column (a,b,c).I know that indexing will work in (a),(a,b),(a,b,c). 
But does indexing work in reverse order (c),(c,b),(c,b,a)??

Comment: the index `(a,b,c)` will allow `WHERE a = ?`, `WHERE a = ? AND b = ?`, `WHERE a = AND b = ? AND c = ?` also it does not matter how the filters are orderd in the `WHERE` clause so `WHERE b = ? AND a = ? AND c = ?` should also work.

Comment: Index work left sided so you can't do `WHERE c = ?` or `WHERE c = ? AND b = ?`, there is a trick which you can do... But it will not that effective because a full index scan is needed if a, b, c are ints you can do `WHERE a >= 1 AND b >= 1 AND c = ?` for `CHAR/VARCHAR` you can do `WHERE a >= 'a' AND b >= 'a' AND c = ?`.. The full index scan will be faster then the full table scan assuming the index file is smaller then the table file

Comment: also your question is to broad to answer, the MySQL optimizer and how it uses indexes is way to complex to answer here.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you use

```
WHERE b = ? AND a = ? AND c = ?
```

MySQL should properly use your index. The order of the ANDs have no importance and the optimizer should rearrange that to find the right path.

However if you start with things like

```
WHERE b < ? AND a = ? AND c > ?
```

It will probably never use the index at all, or only partially.The optimizer will have to take a decision on wether doing a full table scan will be more efficient than partially use the index. That's rather not predictable here, as it depends on different parameters of your own DB : table structure, data, stats accuracy,...

So you might want to create several indexes for that purpose.

Note that if you are on MySQL 8+, you can also create [descending index](http://%20http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-descending-index/) following the < or > you are expecting in your queries.

For my example above, this would probably work well :

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    a INT NOT NULL,
    b INT NOT NULL,
    c INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX bca_desc (b DESC, c ASC, a ASC)
);
```

Comment: *"WHERE b < ? AND a = ? AND c > ?

It will probably never use the index."* Well MySQL should be able the index part of a from the index `(a, b, c)`,  if you do EXPLAIN you see a key_length column which tell you the bytes MySQL is using from a index... but annyway  the MySQL optimizer and how it uses indexes is way to complex to answer here.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are totally right and I have detailed that

Comment: It will gladly use `a,b`, but not `c` (unless it is "covering").